# Making annotated Heatmap R using annHeatmap2

Tags: r, heatmap

Trying to make a heatmap using annHeatmap2 in R (so I can annotate rows with 3 binary variables as well as the row name) the heatmap data and annotation data are in the same csv file as different columns (heatmap data in columns 1:4 and binary annotations thereafter)

my problem is getting the annotation on the rows, as the code below forces the annotations on the columns.

As a subsiduary problem I cannot for the life of me turn the dendrogram/clustering off. Any help there would be great.

```
map1 = annHeatmap2(mydata_matrix[1:4,], ann=list(Col=list(data=pData(mydata_matrix[4:7,]))), cluster=list(Col=list(cuth=3000)))  
plot(map1)
```

an example dataset is enclosed

```
GeneName    wt  basal   aa basal    wt PMA 1h   aa PMA 1h   var1    var2    var3
Osm 79.04263765 87.7338764  271.0823488 78.54386727 0   0   1
Il10    16.19566857 27.7348142  758.0504883 209.5772766 1   1   1
Nr4a1   2850.181935 2867.378369 41778.06162 12366.60255 0   1   1
Zfp36   202.9647756 150.495029  1385.650968 535.7451794 1   1   1
Chka    56.31912295 56.75597066 211.3589101 85.5156186  0   0   0
Phlda1  3303.725954 4276.452597 56005.96237 23852.14205 0   1   0
ENSMUST00000107563  133.9562031 139.1866568 872.5107413 364.9401856 0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Row in annotation list for Row displaying and cluster status "no" for no clustering:
(see ?annHeatmap2)

```
map1 = annHeatmap2(mydata_matrix[1:4,],
ann = list(Row = list(data=pData(mydata_matrix[4:7,]))),
cluster = list(status="no")))
plot(map1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a row dendrogram but hide the dendrogram for the columns, use something like this:
`...,dendrogram = list(Row = list(dendro = as.dendrogram(row.clus)),Col=list(status="hide")),...`

This info is found in the "Creating heatmaps using package Heatplus" vignette.